# HasMany relationship, find child index from child in relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I'm currently trying to access the index of a child in a HasMany relationship in a Laravel project. I have an order with many orderItems, but I can't seem to find a way to access the index of the orderItem I am dealing with from its relationship with the parent Order.

So, basically I want to be able to do $orderItem->order->index() if possible, is there anything within Eloquent that can give me this?

Here's some code to show you how I have the relationships setup...

*Order.php*

```
/**
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class)->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}
```

*OrderItem.php*

```
/**
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```

What I want to do...

```
OrderItem::find(1)->order->index()
```

or something like that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What index are you talking about?

Comment: what do you mean by `index()`??

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin So, if I call $orderItem->order, I get an order model returned with all the orderItems related to it, I'd like to be able to get the index of the current $orderItem I'm dealing with relative to the $order it belongs to.

Comment: @Sohel0415 See above comment for further clarification.

Comment: Still not clear. When you do `$orderItem->order` you get model only without any related items.

Comment: seems he is looking for something like `Order::with('orderItems')->where('id', $id)->first()`

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, You are trying to get all `OrderItem` `ids` related to `Order`. Then You can use [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) to get this-

```
$order = Order::find($orderId);
$ids = $order->orderItems()->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologise to everyone that I confused with the question, what I wanted was to get the index of the current OrderItem I am dealing with as if it had been loaded via a relationship call.

In the end, this is the code that worked for me...

```
$this->$order->orderItems->pluck('id')->search($this->id)
```

This then returned the correct index to me.